# Flex: Does anybody know a TabNavigator component that allows for html labels in the tabs or how to do this?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I'm trying to put html-formatted labels in the tabs of a TabNavigator.

I saw SuperTabNavigator in the FlexLib but it doesn't seem to do the trick for me.

I found this [html button code](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=14186) and was able to inject my own TabBar and have it change the class instantiated by the ClassFactory when a navItem is created.

HtmlTabNavigator:

```
public class HtmlTabNavigator extends TabNavigator
{
    public function HtmlTabNavigator()
    {
        super();
    }


    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        if (!tabBar)
        {
            tabBar = new HtmlTabBar();  // inject my class
            tabBar.name = "tabBar";
            tabBar.focusEnabled = false;
            tabBar.styleName = new StyleProxy(this, tabBarStyleFilters);
            rawChildren.addChild(tabBar);

            if (FlexVersion.compatibilityVersion < FlexVersion.VERSION_3_0)
            {
                tabBar.setStyle("paddingTop", 0);
                tabBar.setStyle("paddingBottom", 0);
                tabBar.setStyle("borderStyle", "none");             
            }
        }

        super.createChildren(); // ommits original TabBar creation but continues in inheritance chain
    }


    public function setHtmlLabels( htmlLabels:Array ):void
    {

        for (var i:uint = 0; i < tabBar.numChildren; i++)
        {
            var button:Button = tabBar.getChildAt( i ) as Button;
            button.label = htmlLabels[ i ];
        }
    }
}
```

HtmlTabBar:

```
public class HtmlTabBar extends TabBar
{
    public function HtmlTabBar()
    {
        super();

        navItemFactory = new ClassFactory(HtmlButton);
    }
}
```

Now I'm having problems with the style of the button as it looks like a regular button and not like a tab anymore. It is not apparent to me why this works when a ButtonBarButton is used.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks
Stefan

Comment: I was able to overcome the style problem for my limited purpose by implementing my own skins for HtmlTabNavigator and the HtmlButton. Would still be interested in a component.

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned, I think its best to built your own component for this scenario. You could consider using a textArea with editable=false for the tab portion since I believe htmlText can be displayed in that component.

Edit: Can you maybe modify the SuperTabNavigator and add in a textArea... so the original label for the tab could be blank (if you cant remove it) then have the textArea on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

With best regards,

Following your example, I tried to specialize the TabBar to use a Custom Button with a Mnemonic Label functionality, but I get a compile time error:

> 1178: Attempted access of inaccessible
>   property navItemFactory through a
>   reference with static type
>   AspMnemonicTabBar.

Reading the Flex Source Code I found it belongs to a private namespace **mx_internal**. So how could I access it to set a new ClassFactory ??

```
package
{
    import mx.controls.TabBar;
    import mx.core.ClassFactory;

    public class AspMnemonicTabBar extends TabBar
    {
        public function AspMnemonicTabBar()
        {
            super();
            navItemFactory = new ClassFactory(AspMnemonicButton);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You import mx.core.mx_internal and say "use namespace mx_internal";

Answer (score 0):

Alessandro, navItemFactory is in namespace mx_internal.  Access it through mx_internal::navItemFactory, or put the following line below your import statements:
use namespace mx_internal;